# Binding controller properties in isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, binding, directive

I am trying to get up to AngularJS directives and scope bindings. I will rather give my code and then ask question :

Here is my directive definition :

```
'use strict';
 (function(){
 var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
 var gem = {name:"Pearl",price:22.5 };
 app.controller("StoreController",function(){
   var self = this;
    self.product = gem;
    self.validateOnSubmit="myForm";

});
app.directive("requireOnSubmit",function(){
   var directiveDefinitionObject = {
       restrict:'A',
       scope : {
           validationFlag : '='
       },
       link : function(scope,ele,attr){
           console.log(scope.validationFlag);
         },
       controller : "StoreController",
       controllerAs : "store",
       bindToController : true
   };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});}());
```

And Here is my html :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="gemStore">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div>
        <h3>{{store.product.name}} </h3>  <h3>{{store.product.price}} </h3>
    </div>
    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="test" require-on-submit />
    </form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Now I want to bind validationOnSubmit property on controller with validationFlag and it should be two-way binding.
      I have tried adding

```
 <input type="text" name="test" require-on-submit      validationFlag="validationOnSubmit"/>
```

and in directive :

```
     scope : {
           validationFlag : '=validationFlag'
       }
```

But doesn't work. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if 2 way binding works with controller properies but the correct syntax would be

```
   validationFlag="store.validationOnSubmit"
```

The StoreController will be initialized twice. Once on the body element and once with the directive. To avoid confusion you should remove the controller from the directive and if you need access to the controller use the `require` propery.

Comment: what should I specify in require property? require="StoreController" ? and accept it as a 4th parameter to directive function.

Comment: No you need to define a directive. You can use `ngController`